# Custom Resources(css, javascript etc.) for common look and feel in all applications

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, frameworks

I have a problem statement, where we wish to create custom CSS, Javascripts etc resources so as to give same look and feel to all our applications to be developed.

**The applications may be developed in GWT, Thingworx, JSP etc and may vary.** We wish to provide a common theme for all the applications with components like:

1) Header - Background, Image, Text

2) Footer - Background, Image, Text

3) Field Labels - Font size, font style etc.

4) Result table headers, their alignment etc.

The list may go long....

**I would like to hear about:**

**1) More such components(like above) which can be part of such concept?**

**2) How to proceed further on this problem statement? - Should we create a common css and import it into various upcoming projects. Or some packaging structure can be given to it so as to give it a shape of a framework.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have similar goals in the company I work for. Our solution was to create custom components either from scratch (using vector graphics for a nice clean scalable UI) or extending/modifying their existing components (for example, creating a tabbed component that lets you hide the tabs and exposes services to select tabs by wiring up to expressions or services)

### Custom Components:

There is no "easy" way to include a custom css block, even in the components they each contain their own .css definitions. However you could create a framework and include it as a dependency of a custom component (which is what we did) which then can make it globally accessible.

Be careful not to pollute the global namespaces, and beware that some variables (namely `s`) will be changed during run time (someone forget a `var` keyword?). Use closures where appropriate.

Custom components take the form of a zip file with a specified folder structure. You may wish to take a look at the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or similar as part of your build process to generate the final minified and optimized copy of your framework, then include it in a package of custom component(s).

### Caution:

Also be aware that the platform currently suffers from exponential degradation of performance relative to the number of components in any given mashup. After about 100 you start to notice sluggishness and delays in Chrome, and IE is nearly unusable. A work-around for this is delegation, to allow the browser to cleanup it's internal lists and b-trees. Using an execution queue (or even simply setTimeout(function(){mycode/call}, 0) will do).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a common CSS and include a link to it in all applications.

No, there is no limit on which HTML elements you can style with this common CSS.